# SQL query for combinations without repetition for top N cases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a query which can be used in (or as) a function and retrieves N combinations of M values from a table.

Example: Input: table with values in one column in multiple rows

#### Case 1

```
N=2
M=4 (Record1 to Record4)
```

Table

```
Record1
Record2
Record3
Record4
```

Output

```
Record1
Record2
Record3
Record4
Record1,Record2
Record1,Record3
Record1,Record4
Record2,Record3
Record2,Record4
Record3,Record4
```

#### Case 2

```
N=3
M=4 (Record1 to Record4)
```

Table

```
Record1
Record2
Record3
Record4
```

Output

```
Record1
Record2
Record3
Record4
Record1,Record2
Record1,Record3
Record1,Record4
Record2,Record3
Record2,Record4
Record3,Record4
Record1,Record2,Record3
Record1,Record2,Record4
Record1,Record3,Record4
Record2,Record3,Record4
```

I am using [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29661/sql-query-for-combinations-without-repetition) as base code for execution

Comment: Rather telling us you *"need"*, please tell us what the question you have is. What have *you* tried to do to solve this problem yourself? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Interesting question. It will be a recursive CTE plus dynamic pivot I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If only a fixed amount of N values per combination is needed, then it can easily be done in a normal SQL.

Simply by using N-1 self-joins.

For example if N = 3 then 2 self-joins :

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(t1.name, ',', t2.name, ',', t3.name) AS names
FROM yourtable t1
JOIN yourtable t2 ON t2.name > t1.name
JOIN yourtable t3 ON t3.name > t2.name;
```

Because of the use of `>` in the joins, that wouldn't return duplicates of the same combinations in a different order.
(Since `A,B,C` = `A,C,B`  = `B,A,C` = `B,C,A` = `C,A,B` = `C,B,A`)

If N is variable,  then such method could be used in a Dynamic Sql that adds N-1 joins to the query string.

However, to get the expected output of the question, to return also N=1 & N=2 & N=3 then we could use that trick in combination with a Recursive CTE.

**For example this T-SQL snippet:**

```
declare @yourtable table ([name] varchar(30));
insert into @yourtable ([name]) values 
('Record1'), 
('Record2'), 
('Record3'), 
('Record4');

WITH RCTE AS 
(
    SELECT 1 as N, t.name as prev_name, cast(t.name as varchar(max)) AS names
    FROM @yourtable t

    UNION ALL

    SELECT N + 1, t.name, CONCAT(r.names,','+ t.name)
    FROM @yourtable t
    JOIN RCTE r ON t.name > r.prev_name AND r.N < 3
)
SELECT names
FROM RCTE
ORDER BY N, names;
```

**Returns:**

```
names
------------------------
Record1
Record2
Record3
Record4
Record1,Record2
Record1,Record3
Record1,Record4
Record2,Record3
Record2,Record4
Record3,Record4
Record1,Record2,Record3
Record1,Record2,Record4
Record1,Record3,Record4
Record2,Record3,Record4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I implemented a traversal algorithm through the combination of names in an alphabetically sorted order up to N names. The algorithm does not traverse through all `2^N-1` combinations as in the [base code](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29661) mentioned.

The algorithm is explained as follows. Denote the `i-th` name is represented by a digit `i` (starting from 1), then the combination of names can be represented by a sequence of **strictly increasing** digits. The strictly increasing constraint eliminates different permutations from the same combination.

Now we can traverse through these representations in an alphabetically increasing order as shown below (like in a real dictionary). One can clearly see, there are 2 keys to the traversal: (1) **when to do a round-up** and (2) **doing it subject to the strictly-increasing constraint**. The rest is to implement them correctly in the code.

**Disclaimer:** Low efficiency, maintainability and scalability! It barely runs on small dataset (38 sec for 1350 combinations from `M=20` and `N=3`). Consider doing such task in a general purpose programming language especially when the dataset is large. e.g. [A pythonic solution with only 4 lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898031/3218693)

**A concept of what the algorithms does**

```
Combination of names
---------------------
1      -- 1 means 'name1'
2
...
n      -- Round up to 2-digit combinations after this number
1,2    -- The lowest digit begins at 2 because (1,1) violates the constraint
1,3
...
1,n
2,3    -- begins at 3 because 2,1 and 2,2 violates the constraint
2,4
....
2,n
.....
(n-1),n  -- Can't round up to (n,n) so here ends the combinations of 2 digits.
1,2,3    -- In general, round-up gives a consecutive increasing sequence 
         -- starting from the rounding digit
1,2,4
....     -- repeat until all wanted combinations are exhausted.
```

And here is the T-SQL code

**Test Dataset and Parameters**

```
use [testdb];
if OBJECT_ID('testdb..test') is not null
    drop table testdb..test;

create table test (
    [name] VARCHAR(10)
);
GO

-- name list, need not be sorted
insert into test([name]) 
values ('name1'),('name2'),('name3'),('name4'),('name5');

-- Number of names used in the combination
declare @N int = 3;
```

**Program**

```
/***** temp variables *****/

-- get number of names
declare @M int;
select @M = count(distinct [name]) from test;
--print @M;

-- array (table variable) of temporary status
declare @arr table (
    digit int primary key,
    val int,
    [name] varchar(max)
)
-- the value of each digits begins from 0
insert @arr(digit, val, [name])
select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by [name]), 0, [name] from test;

-- begin traversal from the first name
update @arr
    set val = 1
    where digit = 1;
-- check:
-- select * from @arr;

-- concatenation of names
DECLARE @cat VARCHAR(max) = ''

-- current value at the lowest digit
declare @val_now int = 1;  -- 1 to N

-- digit pointer and temporary value used for rounding
declare @digit_round int;
declare @val_round int;

-- answer storage
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ans') is not null
    drop table #ans;
create table #ans (
    names varchar(max)
)

/***** Main Loop *****/

declare @flag_terminate int = 0;

while (@flag_terminate = 0) begin
    while @val_now <= @M BEGIN

        /** output current combination **/

        -- select * from @arr;

        set @cat = '';
        -- use cursor to preserve name order
        declare @name_now varchar(100);    
        declare cur cursor local
        for select (select B.[name] from @arr as B where B.digit = A.val) as [name]
            from @arr as A
            where A.val > 0
            order by [name];
        open cur;

        while 1=1 begin
            fetch next from cur into @name_now;
            if @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 break;
            set @cat = case @cat
                           when '' then ''
                           else @cat + ','
                       end + @name_now;
        end
        close cur;
        deallocate cur;

        -- Can also do this if you don't care about name order
        -- Note that 'order by' won't work on subqueries
        -- SELECT @cat = case @cat
        --                   when '' then ''
        --                   else @cat + ','
        --               end + (select B.[name] from @arr as B where B.digit = A.val)
        -- FROM @arr as A
        -- where A.val > 0;

        insert into #ans(names) values (@cat);

        /** Proceed to next combination **/

        -- 1. no round-up case
        if @val_now < @M begin
            set @val_now += 1;
            update @arr
                set val = @val_now
                where digit = 1;
        end
        -- 2. round-up case
        else begin

            -- Find which digit at where the rounding process should end
            set @digit_round = 1            
            while @digit_round <= @M begin
                -- N.B. Ascending alphabatical sorting of name combanitaions implies
                --      max(digit 2) = M - 1 
                --      max(digit 3) = M - 2
                --      ....
                --      max(digit N) = M - N + 1
                set @val_round = (select val from @arr where digit = @digit_round);
                if @val_round < @M - @digit_round + 1
                    break;
                set @digit_round += 1;
            end
            -- print '    digit_round = ' + str(@digit_round)
            -- print '    val_round = ' + str(@val_round)

            -- 2.1 regular round-up case
            --     rounding process ends within N digits
            if @digit_round <= @N begin

                while @digit_round >= 1 begin
                    -- rounded value
                    set @val_round += 1;
                    -- print 'start rounding:'
                    -- print '    digit_round = ' + str(@digit_round)
                    -- print '    val_round = ' + str(@val_round)

                    -- update temp table
                    update @arr
                        set val = @val_round
                        where digit = @digit_round;
                    -- next digit
                    set @digit_round -= 1;
                end
                -- reset loop vars
                set @val_now = @val_round;
            end
            -- 2.2 termination case
            --     rounding process does not end in N digits
            else begin
                -- print 'Termination reached!'
                set @flag_terminate = 1;
                set @val_now = @M + 1;
            end
        end
    end
end

-- output
select * from #ans;
```

**Result**

```
|    | names             |
|----|-------------------|
| 1  | name1             |
| 2  | name2             |
| 3  | name3             |
| 4  | name4             |
| 5  | name5             |
| 6  | name1,name2       |
| 7  | name1,name3       |
| 8  | name1,name4       |
| 9  | name1,name5       |
| 10 | name2,name3       |
| 11 | name2,name4       |
| 12 | name2,name5       |
| 13 | name3,name4       |
| 14 | name3,name5       |
| 15 | name4,name5       |
| 16 | name1,name2,name3 |
| 17 | name1,name2,name4 |
| 18 | name1,name2,name5 |
| 19 | name1,name3,name4 |
| 20 | name1,name3,name5 |
| 21 | name1,name4,name5 |
| 22 | name2,name3,name4 |
| 23 | name2,name3,name5 |
| 24 | name2,name4,name5 |
| 25 | name3,name4,name5 |
```

Tested on SQL Server 2017 latest (linux docker image).

Answer (score 1):

What can be maximum value of `N` & `M` ?

I am using `RBAR` and `dynamic Sql` and `CROSS JOIN`.

```
DECLARE @N INT = 3
DECLARE @M INT = 4 --M=4 (Record1 to Record4)

-- Purpose of #temp
-- Insert your resultset in #temp using RowNumber or Top (where RowNumber=@M or Top(@M))
-- This is easy part 

CREATE TABLE #temp (
    id INT identity(1, 1)
    ,col VARCHAR(50)
    )

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES ('Record1')
    ,('Record2')
    ,('Record3')
    ,('Record4')





DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(500) = ''
DECLARE @Col NVARCHAR(500) = ''
DECLARE @From NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @Where NVARCHAR(500) = ''
DECLARE @Alias NVARCHAR(5)

WHILE (@i <= @N)
BEGIN
    SET @Alias = 't' + cast(@i AS VARCHAR)

    IF (@i = 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @Col = CONCAT (
                @Alias
                ,'.' + 'col'
                )
        SET @From = '#temp ' + @Alias
        SET @Sql = 'select ' + @Col + ' from  ' + @From + ''
    END
    ELSE IF (@i = 2)
    BEGIN
        SET @Col = @Col + '+'',''' + '+' + CONCAT (
                @Alias
                ,'.' + 'col'
                ,' '
                )
        SET @From = @From + ',' + '#temp ' + @Alias
        SET @Where = @Where + 't' + cast(@i - 1 AS VARCHAR) + '.id < t' + cast(@i AS VARCHAR) + '.id'
        SET @Sql = @Sql + ' union all select ' + @Col + '' + 'from ' + @From + ' where ' + @Where
    END
    ELSE IF (@i > 2)
    BEGIN
        SET @Col = @Col + '+'',''' + '+' + CONCAT (
                @Alias
                ,'.' + 'col'
                ,' '
                )
        SET @From = @From + ',' + '#temp ' + @Alias
        SET @Where = @Where + ' and ' + 't' + cast(@i - 1 AS VARCHAR) + '.id < t' + cast(@i AS VARCHAR) + '.id'
        SET @Sql = @Sql + ' union all select ' + @Col + '' + 'from ' + @From + ' where ' + @Where
    END

    SET @i = @i + 1
END

PRINT @Col
PRINT @Sql

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql

DROP TABLE #temp
```

It is working correctly for `N=1,2,3,4.`