# SQL count number of time series events, with some some start or stop entries missing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some start/stop events and I need to count the number of total events but sometimes a start or stop is missing, for example:

```
Time   Event
10:50   START
10:52   STOP
10:59   START
11:01   STOP
11:45   STOP
```

Count(Event) Where Event='START'
Would return 2, I also need to count the missing START value, so the result should be 3. Any ideas on how this could be done? Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible for two start-stop periods to overlap? This is critical for finding unpaired start or stop events.

Comment: Good question, no the events do not overlap at all

Comment: Yeah I guess that should be the case. I have clarified in my answer about the necessary constraints I think there should be.

Answer (score 0):

Two constraints must be met to enable event counting.

1. Two START-STOP periods cannot overlap.
2. Two consecutive and chronologically ordered `START` and `STOP` event cannot be possibly originated from two different events, namely `START+(missing TOP)` and `(missing START)+STOP`.

It the conditions are met, a simple state machine can be implemented to detect the "missing" events. Such a row-by-row logic could (almost always) be implemented using the `cursor` syntax.

N.B. To exemplify the generality of the `cursor` method you can also see other answers [A (update columns)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58209976/3218693), [B (a tedious algo)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58245259/3218693) I made. The code structures are highly similar.

**Test Dataset**

```
use [testdb];
if OBJECT_ID('testdb..test') is not null
    drop table testdb..test;

create table test (
    [time] varchar(50),
    [event] varchar(50),
);

insert into test ([time], [event])
values ('10:50', 'START'),('10:52', 'STOP'),('10:59', 'START'),
       ('11:01', 'STOP'),('11:45', 'STOP'),('11:50', 'STOP'),('11:55', 'START');

select * from test;
```

**Code**

```
/* cursor variables */

-- storage for each row
declare @time varchar(50),
        @event varchar(50),
        @state int = 0,  -- state variable
        @count int = 0;  -- event count

-- open a cursor ordered by [time]
declare cur CURSOR local
for select [time], [event]
    from test
    order by [time]
open cur;

/* main loop */

while 1=1 BEGIN

    /* fetch next row and check termination condition */
    fetch next from cur 
        into @time, @event;

    -- termination condition
    if @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 begin
        -- check unfinished START before exit
        if @state = 1
            set @count += 1;
        -- exit loop
        break;
    end

    /* program body */

    -- case 1. state = 0 (clear state)
    if @state = 0 begin
        -- 1-1. normal case -> go to state 1
        if @event = 'START'
            set @state = 1;
        -- 1-2. a STOP without START -> keep state 0 and count++
        else if @event = 'STOP'
            set @count += 1;
        -- guard
        else 
            print '[Error] Bad event name: ' + @event
    end
    -- case 2. start = 1 (start is found)
    else if @state = 1 begin
        -- 2-1. normal case -> go to state 0 and count++
        if @event = 'STOP' begin
            set @count += 1;
            set @state = 0;            
        end
        -- 2-2. a START without STOP -> keep state 1 and count++
        else if @event = 'START'
            set @count += 1;
        -- guard
        else 
            print '[Error] Bad event name: ' + @event
    end
END

-- cleanup
close cur;
deallocate cur;
```

**Result**

```
print @count;  -- correct answer: 5
```

Tested on SQL Server 2017 (linux docker image, latest version).

Comment: Thanks @cbhuang the method you're showing has me thinking it could also potentially be done with a window function... Perhaps add a column (Next_Event) with the leading value, then add 1 if Event='Start' and Next_Event='Stop', and ALSO add 1 if Event=Next_Event. I think I'll try both ways and compare results.

Comment: In terms of I/O efficiency, the cursor method require only 1 pass of data (ignoring sorting which is required to be done anyway). Creating a Next_Event variable may have the potential to avoid cursor use, but the efficiency loss may be detrimental. This is also to be noted when your data is large.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could count each start and then each "stop" where the preceding event is not a start:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*,
             lag(event) over (order by time) as prev_event
      from t
     ) t
where event = 'start' or
      (prev_event = 'stop' and event = 'stop');
```